# Break frame in beamer

Tags: beamer

I want to break a frame.  I used `\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]` and I have a problem:
the first frame is blank and the second frame shows complete content.

```
\documentclass[12pt, compress, red]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm, mathabx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics,graphpap}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}



\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Một số tính chất của chuỗi Fourier}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Tuyến tính} \pause
    Nếu hai hàm $f$ và $g$ tuàn hoàn chu kỳ $T$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier  với các hệ số lấy từ các tập $\{a_k,b_k\}$ và $\{c_k,d_k\}$ thì hàm $\alpha f+\beta g$  có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier với hệ số tương ứng $\alpha a_k+\beta c_k,\alpha b_k+\beta d_k,$ với $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.
        \pause
    \item \textbf{Tịnh tiến} \pause
    Hàm $f(t)$ tuần hoàn với chu kỳ $T$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier dưới dạng phức, với các hệ số lấy từ tập $\{A_k\}$ và $a$ là một hằng số thì hàm $f(t-a)$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier vơi các hệ số lấy từ tập $\{A_{k}.e^{\frac{-2i\pi ka}{T}}\}$ \\
     \pagebreak

    \item Hệ số $a_k,b_k,c_k$ là hệ số "tốt nhất" khi xấp xỉ hàm $f$ bằng đa thức lượng giác, với sai số theo nghĩa trung bình bình phương.     
\item Bất đẳng thức Bessel \pause
    $$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx\right)^2\le \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x))^2dx$$ \pause
    Cho $n\rightarrow +\infty$ ta được công thức Parseval \pause
    $$2\pi a^2_0+\pi(a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2+\cdots+)=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x))^2dx$$
    \item Sai số giữa chuỗi Fourier của hàm $f$ với hàm $f$ dần tới $0$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I am not able to produce your problem after adding `\documentclass{beamer}`.

Comment: I write full code

Comment: @Hungnguyen Please see the answer below.

Comment: Please take into account Till Tantau's (the author of `beamer`) recommendation regarding `allowframebreaks` (page 35 of the `beamer` manual): "Do *not* use the option `allowframebreaks` except for long bibliographies." I provided an answer below without `allowframebreaks`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`allowframebreaks` doesn't support overlays. Hence remove all those `\pause` and then it works. Also it is better to use `\framebreak` instead of `\pagebreak`

```
\documentclass[12pt, compress, red]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm, mathabx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics,graphpap}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}
\begin{document}



\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]
    \frametitle{Một số tính chất của chuỗi Fourier}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item \textbf{Tuyến tính}
    Nếu hai hàm $f$ và $g$ tuàn hoàn chu kỳ $T$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier  với các hệ số lấy từ các tập $\{a_k,b_k\}$ và $\{c_k,d_k\}$ thì hàm $\alpha f+\beta g$  có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier với hệ số tương ứng $\alpha a_k+\beta c_k,\alpha b_k+\beta d_k,$ với $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

    \item \textbf{Tịnh tiến}
    Hàm $f(t)$ tuần hoàn với chu kỳ $T$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier dưới dạng phức, với các hệ số lấy từ tập $\{A_k\}$ và $a$ là một hằng số thì hàm $f(t-a)$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier vơi các hệ số lấy từ tập $\{A_{k}.e^{\frac{-2i\pi ka}{T}}\}$ \\
     \framebreak

    \item Hệ số $a_k,b_k,c_k$ là hệ số "tốt nhất" khi xấp xỉ hàm $f$ bằng đa thức lượng giác, với sai số theo nghĩa trung bình bình phương.
\item Bất đẳng thức Bessel
    $$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx\right)^2\le \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x))^2dx$$
    Cho $n\rightarrow +\infty$ ta được công thức Parseval
    $$2\pi a^2_0+\pi(a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2+\cdots+)=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x))^2dx$$
    \item Sai số giữa chuỗi Fourier của hàm $f$ với hàm $f$ dần tới $0$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would not use `\framebreak` and force the break but leave it to latex to break the frame.

Comment: @Hungnguyen You are welcome. Please don't forget that you can accept the answer that best solved your problem by clicking the green check mark nest to it. For details please refer to [How do you accept an answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1852/how-do-you-accept-an-answer). Beside this, you can also up vote once you acquire a minimum of 15 rep points.

Comment: Yes, I will remember that. Thanks for your hint Harisk Kumar

Answer (score 5):

Please take into account Till Tantau's (the author of `beamer`) recommendation regarding `allowframebreaks` (page 35 of the `beamer` manual):

> Do not use the option `allowframebreaks` except for long bibliographies.

I propose another alternative giving you the possibility to still use overlays by simply using two frames;  using `\storecounter` at the end of the first `enumerate` you store the counter value and then `\continuecounter` will take care of appropriately resuming the counter for the list:

```
\documentclass[12pt, compress, red]{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsxtra,amssymb,latexsym, amscd,amsthm, mathabx}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[mathscr]{eucal}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[utf8]{vietnam}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{graphics,graphpap}
\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\usetheme{Warsaw}

\newcounter{tmp}
\newcommand\savecounter{\setcounter{tmp}{\value{enumi}}}
\newcommand\continuecounter{\setcounter{enumi}{\value{tmp}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Một số tính chất của chuỗi Fourier-I}
    \begin{enumerate}[<+->]
    \item \textbf{Tuyến tính}
    Nếu hai hàm $f$ và $g$ tuàn hoàn chu kỳ $T$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier  với các hệ số lấy từ các tập $\{a_k,b_k\}$ và $\{c_k,d_k\}$ thì hàm $\alpha f+\beta g$  có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier với hệ số tương ứng $\alpha a_k+\beta c_k,\alpha b_k+\beta d_k,$ với $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$.

    \item \textbf{Tịnh tiến}
    Hàm $f(t)$ tuần hoàn với chu kỳ $T$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier dưới dạng phức, với các hệ số lấy từ tập $\{A_k\}$ và $a$ là một hằng số thì hàm $f(t-a)$ có khai triển thành chuỗi Fourier vơi các hệ số lấy từ tập $\{A_{k}.e^{\frac{-2i\pi ka}{T}}\}$ \\
  \savecounter
  \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}[<+->]
    \frametitle{Một số tính chất của chuỗi Fourier-II}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \continuecounter
    \item Hệ số $a_k,b_k,c_k$ là hệ số "tốt nhất" khi xấp xỉ hàm $f$ bằng đa thức lượng giác, với sai số theo nghĩa trung bình bình phương.
\item Bất đẳng thức Bessel
    $$\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi}\left(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}a_k\cos kx+b_k\sin kx\right)^2\le \int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x))^2dx$$
    Cho $n\rightarrow +\infty$ ta được công thức Parseval
    $$2\pi a^2_0+\pi(a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2+\cdots+)=\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} (f(x))^2dx$$
    \item Sai số giữa chuỗi Fourier của hàm $f$ với hàm $f$ dần tới $0$
    \end{enumerate}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]